# Trying to wrap the header of data frame /excel but gives me error

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, word-wrap

```
Final_Inv = Inv_report2[["Product ID","Product","Net Activations","Books(at warehouse)","Books(Received by Retailer)","In Transit","Activated","Lost/Stolen (After Activation)","Lost/Stolen(Before Activation)","Total stock at Retailer","Activations(Books)","Stock in Network(Weeks)","Sell Through(%)","Stock at warehouse(Week)","Game Start Date"]]


with pd.ExcelWriter('K:\SnW Project\Inventory Report\Output Excels\Output.xlsx') as writer:
    Final_Inv.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'center'}).to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Inv_report',index = 0,startrow=0, startcol=0)
    workbook  = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['Inv_report']
    format.set_text_wrap
    worksheet.set_row('A:Z',30,format)
    write.save()
```

when I try to wrap the header row with above code it gives me below error.
**ERROR : **

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [29], in <cell line: 64>()
     66 workbook  = writer.book
     67 worksheet = writer.sheets['Inv_report']
---> 68 format.set_text_wrap
     69 worksheet.set_column('A:Z',30,format)
     70 write.save()

AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'set_text_wrap'
```

Tried changing the few things around code but no success

Answer (score 0):

Because [**`format`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) is a built-in function.

Can you try this:

```
cell_format = workbook.add_format()
cell_format.set_text_wrap()
```

Full code:

```
Final_Inv = Inv_report2[["Product ID","Product","Net Activations","Books(at warehouse)","Books(Received by Retailer)","In Transit","Activated","Lost/Stolen (After Activation)","Lost/Stolen(Before Activation)","Total stock at Retailer","Activations(Books)","Stock in Network(Weeks)","Sell Through(%)","Stock at warehouse(Week)","Game Start Date"]]


with pd.ExcelWriter('K:\SnW Project\Inventory Report\Output Excels\Output.xlsx') as writer:
    Final_Inv.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'center'}).to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Inv_report',index = 0,startrow=0, startcol=0)
    workbook  = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['Inv_report']
    cell_format = workbook.add_format()
    cell_format.set_text_wrap()
    worksheet.set_row('A:Z',30,cell_format)
    write.save()
```